# How to convert JSON text into objects using C#

Tags: c#, json

How can I convert the following JSON response to a C# object?

```
{ 
    "err_code": "0", 
    "org": "CGK", 
    "des": "SIN", 
    "flight_date": "20120719",
    "schedule": [
        ["W2-888","20120719","20120719","1200","1600","03h00m","737-200","0",[["K","9"],["F","9"],["L","9"],["M","9"],["N","9"],["P","9"],["C","9"],["O","9"]]],
        ["W2-999","20120719","20120719","1800","2000","01h00m","MD-83","0",[["K","9"],["L","9"],["M","9"],["N","9"]]]
    ]
}
```

Comment: if you are using an MVC there is a lot that is does out of the box to support that conversion.  You can also check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c

Comment: i face problem to build class for that json reponse can any one build the class for that json response

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I recommend you to use [`JSON.NET`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx). it is an open source library to serialize and deserialize your c# objects into json and Json objects into .net objects.

Here's some stuff from their website:

**Deserialization Example:**

```
string json = @"{
  'Name': 'Bad Boys',
  'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
  'Genres': [
    'Action',
    'Comedy'
  ]
}";

Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);

string name = m.Name;
// Bad Boys
```

**Performance Comparison To Other JSON serializiation Techniques**
[image]

Comment: @Vish: You should have main class e.g; FlightInfo with properties, one property should be the List of Schedule e.g; List<Schedule>. Schedule is the 2nd class which has also some properties. See your json string properly

Comment: @Talha:Ya but schedule contains what type of properties because in schedule there are arrays inside array

Answer (score 136):

1. To create a class off a json string, copy the string.
2. **In Visual Studio, in the menu at the top, click Edit > Paste special > Paste Json as classes**.
3. Install Newtonsoft.Json via Nuget
4. Paste the following code into your project, "jsonString" being the variable you want to deserialize :

   `Rootobject r = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonString);`
5. Don't forget to rename Rootobject to be more descriptive eg `ILoveTheSmellOfNapalmInTheMorning`-that was a joke

Comment: Yes, I think this really what was asked for at the time. It was kind of a roundabout thing in VS2012 (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526659/how-to-show-the-paste-json-class-in-visual-studio-2012-when-clicking-on-paste) Now in VS2017, very straightforward.

Comment: Extremely useful and when doing a conversion using JsonConvert you may have to create the delegate as an array. In my case this is what I had to do in order to convert the JSON string to a class. JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PanelFootnotes[]>(FootnoteJSON.Value)

Comment: I recently found the need to work with JSON and came across this site https://json2csharp.com/ and now I discover that VS does it for you. Good information to have.

Comment: This doesn't work with JSON files with size > 5 MB

Comment: Thank you for this tip. On a different note, the same applicable for JetBrains Rider as well: **Edit > Paste > Paste Special: JSON as Classes / JSON as Records**

Answer (score 64):

First create a class to represent your json data.

```
public class MyFlightDto
{
    public string err_code { get; set; }
    public string org { get; set; } 
    public string flight_date { get; set; }
    // Fill the missing properties for your data
}
```

**Using Newtonsoft JSON serializer** to [Deserialize a json string](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm) to it's corresponding class object.

```
var jsonInput = "{ org:'myOrg',des:'hello'}"; 
MyFlightDto flight = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyFlightDto>(jsonInput);
```

Or Use  `JavaScriptSerializer` to convert it to a class(*not recommended as the newtonsoft json serializer seems to perform better*).

```
string jsonInput="have your valid json input here"; //
JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Customer objCustomer  = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<Customer >(jsonInput)
```

Assuming you want to convert it to a `Customer` classe's instance. Your class should looks similar to the `JSON` structure (Properties)

Comment: I am not able to build class for that json response

Answer (score 5):

copy your Json and paste at textbox on http://json2csharp.com/ and click on Generate button,

A cs class will be generated use that cs file as below:

```
var generatedcsResponce = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(yourJson);
```

where `RootObject` is the name of the generated cs file;

Comment: Great, another similar useful online tool, which might help, here it is:
https://www.minify-beautify.com/json-to-csharp-class-online/
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will take a json string and turn it into any class you specify

```
public static T ConvertJsonToClass<T>(this string json)
    {
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var res = Json; //Json that has to be converted

        Response resp = new Response();
        resp = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Response>(res);

        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}

public class Response
{
    public bool isValidUser { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public int resultKey { get; set; }
}
```