# How to show the "paste Json class" in visual studio 2012 when clicking on Paste Special?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2012, json.net

I am trying to use the past special feature in vs 2012 in order to generate c# class for my Json data. 
I downloaded the Json.New from NewtonSoft from Nuget and then added a new .cs class the copied my json data to clipboard but when I go to Edit-> Paste Special --> I can only see: Paste XML As Classes only the Paste Json as Classes feature is not showing. Any Suggestions?
Thanks you in advance

This is what I am getting and please note that I have installed Newtonsoft.Json already:

[image]
<sub>(source: [indevcogroup.com](http://icms.indevcogroup.com/uploads/untitled.png))</sub>

Answer (score 22):

I created a new project, installed Newtonsoft.Json and added a class.

If you have your class file open, copy your Json data and choose Edit -> Paste Special you will see both the options:

[image: Paste Special with Json Option]

If you have some other kind of file open (e.g. app.config), you only see "Paste JSON as As Classes" (and it's greyed out)

[image: Paste Special - 1 option and greyed out]

It does seem a bit flaky though - sometimes I had to recopy the data before it would show up.

Try a) recopying your data b) playing around with what windows you've got open c) reinstalling the extension

Comment: The problem is when I am clicking on Paste Special I get Paste XML as Classes no Json. Please check the link I added. Thank you

Comment: Yes i did but it did not work. Is there any other software that i can use in order to get my JSON data and then cache it inside my application? my target is to apply a local data caching in my windows 8 app

Answer (score 10):

When selecting the **Edit > Paste Special** menu while in the code of a class file, make sure that the Visual Studio project that your class file is under has its 'Target Framework' set to:

.NET Framework **3.5**+ for 'Paste **JSON** as Classes'

.NET Framework **4.5**+ for 'Paste **XML** as Classes'

Otherwise these options do not appear.

The 'Target Framework' setting is under the **Project Properties > Application**.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=41532 to get the option to appear under Paste Special.

Comment: In case the link goes dead in the future, the download points to "ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012"

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and discovered that you should have valid JSON text in your clipboard.

Steps to get it to work:

1. Install Web Essentials for your version of VS (Visual Studio). [Web Essentials Download page](http://vswebessentials.com/download)
2. Create empty class file in VS.
3. Copy valid JSON text into clipboard.
4. You will now see the "Paste Json as Classes" under Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste Json as Classes

Sample input:

```
    {
       "firstName":"John",
       "lastName":"Smith",
       "age":25,
       "address":{
          "streetAddress":"21 2nd Street",
          "city":"New York",
          "state":"NY",
          "postalCode":"10021"
       },
       "phoneNumber":[
          {
             "type":"home",
             "number":"212 555-1234"
          },
          {
             "type":"fax",
             "number":"646 555-4567"
          }
       ]
    }
```

Sample output:

```
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public Address address { get; set; }
        public Phonenumber[] phoneNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string streetAddress { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string postalCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class Phonenumber
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string number { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  I was selecting the class from the solution explorer, and getting only the `XML` option.  I finally put my carrot directly in the curly braces of the `public class`, then navigated to Edit->'Paste Special'.

Edit: Correction, that generates a class inside the class.  Instead, I'm going to put my insertion point somewhere in the namespace. 'Paste JSON classes' then generates a public class Rootobject{} and other public classes that are nested in the clipboard JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install update for Visual Studio
I installed update v4 and now I have an option "Paste JSON As Classes"