# FSharp.Data.JsonProvider - Getting json from types

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data

The FSharp.Data.JsonProvider provides a means to go from json to an F# type. Is it possible to go in the reverse direction i.e. declare an instance of one of the types created by FSharp.Data.JsonProvider, set the field values to be what I need, and then get the equivalent json?

I've tried things like this,

```
type Simple = JsonProvider<""" { "name":"John", "age":94 } """>

let fred = Simple( 
            Age = 5, // no argument or settable property 'Age'
            Name = "Fred")
```

Comment: When I asked the creators back in September 2013, the answer was *no*: https://twitter.com/ploeh/status/382481359551594496

Comment: `DataContractJsonSerializer`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

The latest version of F# Data now supports this. See the last example in http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html.

Your example would be:

```
type Simple = JsonProvider<""" { "name":"John", "age":94 } """>
let fred = Simple.Root(age = 5, name = "Fred")
```

Answer (score -2):

This is one area where C# has an edge over F#, at least in Visual Studio. You can copy your JSON example code into the clipboard and in Visual Studio use the Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON As Classes  and it will create a class to match the JSON example. From there you can easily use the class in F#.

More details on paste special [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18527793/3382930)

Hopefully a matching feature will come for F# soon too.

Comment: I guess the point of TP is you dont need to have that class written down, it is generated on the fly..

Comment: @nicolas I'm not sure I agree, since the asker wants to assign values to the TP class, it would need to be recorded 'somewhere' (the JSON file is 'somewhere'). I think a class definition is clearer than a JSON file.

Comment: my point is that a TP's purpose is, as I understand it, to not have any intermediate class. that is irrespective of your use of the generated type (mutate, write, send over the wire etc...)

Comment: While that may be true Pete, that doesn't help the poster with his/her problem. They wanted to know how to do something in F#.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13349844)