# Convert JObject to anonymous type object

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, json.net, deserialization

Im trying to parse in C# using Newtonsoft.Json JSON to anonymous type to use its fields with reflection. But in any ways I get `JObject`. In runtime it turns out not at all what I need:

[image]

What should I use to get anonymous type object from JSON parsing, like when I use `dynamic cleanDynamic = new { SomeProperty = "SomeValue" };`?
Only one similar way I found: `JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json1, definition)`, but I can't provide definition, I don't know it!
Maybe I have to use another lib? I'm using .net core 2.2.

Comment: Do you want to deserialize to a **dynamic** type, as in one that implements [`IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2), or an [**anonymous** type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types), a static type that encapsulates a set of read-only properties defined at compile time?  Because `JObject` is already a dynamic type, but if you prefer you can deserialize to `ExpandoObject` instead.

Comment: @dbc yes, i suppose question is not correct, i mean to anonymous type, but without defenetion. I will reformulate.

Comment: Then this is difficult and doesn't seem to be widely useful.  But there's already a basic answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29428640/344280) to [C# anonymous object with properties from dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29413942/344280) that does this using `AssemblyBuilder` and `Reflection.Emit`.  You would need to modify that code to be recursive.

Comment: btw i found a video, where DeserializeObject returns anonymous type https://youtu.be/Udg-S-_9t8k?t=114

Comment: Another option would be to use [tag:f#] and the [JSON Type Provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html).  Basically it constructs a runtime type by parsing some JSON.  See e.g. [FSharp.Data.JsonProvider - Getting json from types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22280155).  You could parse the JSON in an f# project then return it to c# for later use.