# Complicated deserialization json with nested classes c#

Tags: c#, json, nested, deserialization

I have generated classes using json2csharp. 
There is all good in `var content = response.Content;` 
I also have deserialized the main class:

```
var responseData1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectChangeLocation>(content);
```

But I need to retrieve lat and lng from this class:

```
public class Location
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to make `var responseData1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Location>(content);` to retrieve coordinates. But `lat` and `lng` in `responseData1` are empty if I do it directly. How can I get them?
This is code generated by json2csharp:

```
 public class AddressComponent
    {
        public string long_name { get; set; }
        public string short_name { get; set; }
        public List<string> types { get; set; }
    }

    public class Northeast
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Southwest
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bounds
    {
        public Northeast northeast { get; set; }
        public Southwest southwest { get; set; }
    }

    public class Location
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Northeast2
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Southwest2
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Viewport
    {
        public Northeast2 northeast { get; set; }
        public Southwest2 southwest { get; set; }
    }

    public class Geometry
    {
        public Bounds bounds { get; set; }
        public Location location { get; set; }
        public string location_type { get; set; }
        public Viewport viewport { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public List<AddressComponent> address_components { get; set; }
        public string formatted_address { get; set; }
        public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
        public string place_id { get; set; }
        public List<string> types { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObjectChangeLocation
    {
        public List<Result> results { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }
```

The jsonString is:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Vinnytsia",
               "short_name" : "Vinnytsia",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Vinnyts'ka city council",
               "short_name" : "Vinnyts'ka city council",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Vinnyts'ka oblast",
               "short_name" : "Vinnyts'ka oblast",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Ukraine",
               "short_name" : "UA",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Vinnytsia, Vinnyts'ka oblast, Ukraine",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 49.27902,
                  "lng" : 28.5710879
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 49.190448,
                  "lng" : 28.3681799
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 49.233083,
               "lng" : 28.468217
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 49.27902,
                  "lng" : 28.5710879
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 49.1906116,
                  "lng" : 28.3681799
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJiWRaGWVbLUcR_nTd7lnh1Ms",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: What do you receive when accessing the location through property responseData1.Geometry.Location?

Answer (score 0):

@dbc helped me to find the solution according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371365/google-geocoding-json-parsing-issue-in-c-sharp)

```
        get_coordinates.Click += delegate
        {
            string city_val = change_location.Text;
            var client = new RestClient("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=");
            var request = new RestRequest(city_val, Method.GET);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content;

            var responseData1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectChangeLocation>(content);

            if (content == null||content=="")
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "City is empty or incorrect", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
            else
            {
                foreach(var data in responseData1.results)
                {
                    var lat = data.geometry.location.lat;
                }
            }
            // Toast.MakeText(this, content, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            Console.WriteLine(content.ToString());
        };
```