# How to create Models in ASP.Net for multi level Json format?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json2csharp

Problem Specification:  Build a web api in asp.net to post multi level json formatted data.

Json Format:

```
{
  "InfoList:"[
    {
    "Name": " Sample String 1",
    "URL": " Sample String2",
    "Info":[
        {
            "ZIP": " Sample String3 "
            "status": "Sample String4"
        }
    ]
     }
   ]
}
```

I tried to solve this problem. My models are given bellow:

My Models:

```
public class Information : InfoList
    {
        public InfoList InfoList { get; set; }
    }

public class InfoList 
        {

            public string Name { get; set; }

            public string URL { get; set; }

            public Info info { get; set; }
        }

public class Info
    {
        public string ZIP{ get; set; }

        public string status { get; set; }

    }
```

Those models Generates this kind of Json Format:

```
{
  "InfoList": {
    "Name": "sample string 1",
    "URL": "sample string 2",
    "Info": {
      "ZIP": "sample string 1",
      "status": "sample string 2"
    }
  },
  "Name": "sample string 1",
  "URL": "sample string 2",
  "Info": {
    "ZIP": "sample string 1",
    "status": "sample string 2"
  }
}
```

I need those parentheses exactly like the problem specification.What to do? I am working with ASP.Net Web API controller.

Comment: You need to make the properties collections - `public IEnumerable<InfoList> InfoList { get; set; }` and `public IEnumerable<Info> info { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just copy your JSON then create C# Class file. Then click Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes. Thats it...

You need Visual Studio for this.

**For more information please see below link**

[How to show the "paste Json class" in visual studio 2012 when clicking on Paste Special?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526659/how-to-show-the-paste-json-class-in-visual-studio-2012-when-clicking-on-paste)

**Valid JSON**

```
{
    "InfoList":  {
        "Name": " Sample String 1",
        "URL": " Sample String2",
        "Info": [
            {
                "ZIP": " Sample String3 ",
                "status": "Sample String4"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**So your class must be like this.**

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Infolist InfoList { get; set; }
}

public class Infolist
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public Info[] Info { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    public string ZIP { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You might want to mention that this needs Visual Studio. It's not anything inherent for C#.

Answer (score 1):

You're inheriting `Information` from `InfoList` so naturally it will get the fields `Name`, `URL` etc. Remove the inheritance and change the `InfoList` and `Info` members into arrays or lists and you get what you want.

```
public class Information
{
    public InfoList[] InfoList { get; set; }
}

public class InfoList 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public Info[] info { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    public string ZIP{ get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hello Sami. This code return s me bellow json format - >

Comment: This code is not giving me the exact Json format. 
My Post Method: 

 public string Post([FromBody]Information value)
        {
            string hello;
            return "value";
        }
Is there any problem with my post method ??

Comment: @Pongta That code will not return anything in json format so hard to say...

Comment: Sorry for my wrong comment. Basically I tried to say something else. By the way my problem is solved. Your classes works properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://json2csharp.com/ online tool to create c# class from json data string. Just copy your json and get classes.