# Missing the "Paste JSON as Classes" option but have "Paste XML as Classes" in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have Visual Studio Community Edition 2017. It's completely up to date and I have ASP.NET and web development option installed. In fact, until I did, I didn't see the XML option either. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling that option as I've seen mentioned online, but that didn't help.

- I'm making sure that my cursor is placed in the correct location of a
  new class that I create, and that I have properly formatted JSON in
  the clipboard.
- I have also tried every version of .NET from 4.5 on up.
- I made sure I didn’t accidently remove it from “Tools, Customize, Commands tab, select “Menu bar: Edit | Paste Special”.
- I tried resetting all settings.
- I also tried every suggestion in this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526659/how-to-show-the-paste-json-class-in-visual-studio-2012-when-clicking-on-paste) with no luck (neither did that poster)
- I also tried VS in safe mode, with all extensions off.

Any ideas please?

[image]

Comment: Add a comment on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/15266/paste-xml-as-classes-is-missing.html (MS doesn't allow to vote for closed issue)

Comment: As a workaround I used VS 2015- fortunately I do not use the feature often.

Comment: @Micahel Thanks for the link.

Comment: Also missing in enterprise. As a workaround http://json2csharp.com/ can be used.