# C# parsing json array and picking values

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to parse this json array:
https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=60&aggregate=3&e=Kraken

Idea is read some values for each timestamp(not all needed).
How I could data of 1st time-stamp, close, high, low, open?

I've tried several methods I used for simple json stings but this seem to be challenge for me and can't get data read any ways I've tried.

First I made separate class file like this:

```
namespace HistoryData
{
    class DataQuery
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public string Close { get; set; }
        public string High { get; set; }
        public string Low { get; set; }
        public string Open { get; set; }
        public string Volumefrom { get; set; }
        public string Volumeto { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then parse:

```
const string url = @"https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute?
fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=30&aggregate=3&e=Kraken";
var client = new WebClient();
var content = client.DownloadString(url);
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataQuery>>(content);
var Time1 = (results[1].Time);
var Close1 = (results[1].Close);
```

NOT WORKING

Comment: What problem are you facing, exactly? Read [ask].

Comment: Here are some tips you can google to get  you to a point where you can ask a good question. Create a class with properties that match the JSON schema. Use JSON.Net to deserialize the JSON to an object or list. Use that to get your datra.

Comment: You mention you have tried different things, can you elaborate on what your approach was? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

If you format your JSON with https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ you will see the outermost container is an object, not an array:

```
{
   "Response":"Success",
   "Type":100,
   "Aggregated":true,
   "Data": [/*...*/],
   "TimeTo":1513705980,
   "TimeFrom":1513695060,
   "FirstValueInArray":true,
   "ConversionType":{
      "type":"force_direct",
      "conversionSymbol":""
   }
}
```

Thus you need to deserialize to an appropriate root data model that reflects this JSON structure.  Your `DataQuery` reflects only the nested `"Data"` objects.  You can use http://json2csharp.com/ or [Paste JSON as Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18526659/3744182) to design that model for you:

```
public class Datum
{
    public long time { get; set; }
    public decimal close { get; set; }
    public decimal high { get; set; }
    public decimal low { get; set; }
    public decimal open { get; set; }
    public double volumefrom { get; set; }
    public double volumeto { get; set; }
}

public class ConversionType
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string conversionSymbol { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Response { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public bool Aggregated { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> Data { get; set; }
    public long TimeTo { get; set; }
    public long TimeFrom { get; set; }
    public bool FirstValueInArray { get; set; }
    public ConversionType ConversionType { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize like:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
var results = root.Data;

var Time1 = (results[1].time);
var Close1 = (results[1].close);
```

Notes:

- Since `close`, `high`, `low` and `open` look to be currency values, I modified their types to `decimal`.
- I also changed the timestamps to `long` for safety.

Working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JspnJP).