# Newtonsoft DeserializeObject not calling constructor

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am having an issue with deserializing decimal value correctly. A suggestion on the site was to use a constructor but it is not calling that constructor.

Here is the JSON:

```
{
    "errors": false,
    "response": {
        "entities": [
        {
            "currency_id": "1",
            "balance": 1e-8,
            "address": ""
        },
        {
            "currency_id": "2",
            "balance": 0,
            "address": null
        },
        {
            "currency_id": "3",
            "balance": 0.09865566,
            "address": null
        },
        {
            "currency_id": "5",
            "balance": 0,
            "address": null
        },
        {
            "currency_id": "6",
            "balance": 0,
            "address": null
        }]
    },
    "pagination": {
        "items_per_page": 100,
        "total_items": 5,
        "current_page": 1,
        "total_pages": 1
   }
}
```

My classes:

```
public class ApiResponse<T> where T : class
{
    public bool Errors { get; set; }
    public T Response { get; set; }
}

public class ApiPagingResponse<T> : ApiResponse<T> where T : class
{
    public Pagination Pagination { get; set; }
}

public class GetBalanceListResponse
{
    public GetBalanceListResponseEntity Entity { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject]
public class GetBalanceListResponseEntity
{

    [JsonConstructor]
    public GetBalanceListResponseEntity([JsonProperty("currency_id")]string currencyId, [JsonProperty("balance")]string balance, [JsonProperty("address")]string address)
    {
        CurrencyId = currencyId;
        Balance = decimal.Parse(balance, NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint,
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Address = address;
    }

    [JsonProperty("currency_id")]
    public string CurrencyId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("balance")]
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I call it using this:

```
 var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiPagingResponse<GetBalanceListResponse>>(stringResult);
```

Where `stringResult` is the json string I want to deserizalize.

Currently it just returns null for the Entity property of the response.  All my other serialization works fine with this method, the problem is with `"balance": 1e-8,`

Has anyone dealt with a similar issue and can be of assistance with this?

Comment: In `GetBalanceListResponse`, `public GetBalanceListResponseEntity Entity { get; set; }` should be `public List<GetBalanceListResponseEntity> Entities { get; set; }`.  Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FDirUE).  Otherwise your code basically works.

Comment: @dbc now I feel like a complete idiot

Comment: @dbc if you could add this as an answer I can mark it as accepted, thanks

Comment: answer added as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of [`[JsonConstructor]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm#JsonConstructorAttribute) is correct.  Your only problem is that, in `GetBalanceListResponse`, the method

```
public GetBalanceListResponseEntity Entity { get; set; }
```

should be

```
public List<GetBalanceListResponseEntity> Entities { get; set; }
```

This is because, in the JSON, the corresponding property `response.entities` is an array:

```
{
    "errors": false,
    "response": {
        "entities": [
            // Entity values omitted
        ]
    },
    // Pagination omitted
}
```

With this fix, the constructor is called and your code basically works.  Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FDirUE).

To avoid this sort of problem in the future, you could use an automatic code-generation tool such as http://json2csharp.com/, [Paste JSON as Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18526659/3744182) or https://jsonutils.com/ to generate appropriate classes from your JSON, then modify as required, e.g. by making the auto-generated types generic.