# Get latitude and Longitude from Google Geo Code JSON in MVC(C#)

Tags: c#, api, model-view-controller, google-geocoding-api, google-geolocation

I am having trouble to retrieve values from JSON results received from google geo code API

Function

```
 public static async Task GetLatLogFromAddress()
        {     
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                Uri Inputuri = new Uri("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=123+N+TRY+Street+Paul,+MN&key=APIKey");
                client.BaseAddress = Inputuri;

                // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                // List data response.
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress); ;  // Blocking call! Program will wait here until a response is received or a timeout occurs.
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Parse the response body

                    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    dynamic jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);
                    foreach(var geo in jsonData)
                    {
                        var lat = (decimal)geo[0].geometry.location.lat;
                        var longi = (decimal)geo[0].geometry.location.lng;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);

                } 
                client.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Results in JSON are

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Winnetka",
               "short_name" : "Winnetka",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Los Angeles",
               "short_name" : "LA",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Los Angeles County",
               "short_name" : "Los Angeles County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Winnetka, Los Angeles, CA, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 34.2355209,
                  "lng" : -118.5534191
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 34.1854649,
                  "lng" : -118.588536
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 34.2048586,
               "lng" : -118.5739621
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 34.2355209,
                  "lng" : -118.5534191
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 34.1854649,
                  "lng" : -118.588536
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ0fd4S_KbwoAR2hRDrsr3HmQ",
         "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

These are the results we get from Google GeoCode API

I am trying to get Latitude and Longitude but I get an error that Geo does not contain any definition of geometry. How can I access JSON results received from google geo code API?

Comment: @mjwills I updated the question with results. Thank you

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/18527793/34092?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);
foreach(var item in data.results)
{
    var lat = (decimal)(item.geometry.location.lat);
    var longi = (decimal)(item.geometry.location.lng);
}
```

The problem was that you believed `jsonData` represented `results` when in fact, it was an object which contained the `results` array.

Comment: Can you also let me know how can I get locality from the above results?

Comment: Can you exactly specify the property name you are interested? (in the JSON)

Comment: I want the long_name which is Los Angeles and the type is locality

Comment: You can see here https://pastebin.com/QgbG1tVp how you can retrieve what you need. Be sure you include all the necessary namespaces.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am trying to build a search functionality in C# that looks at providers address in database and compares with zip code/address user added and show result ordered by closeness of distance. I am calculating the distance using GeoCoordinates. I am having issues of using that in query. Can we chat and can you help me regarding this?

Comment: If you reply, we should get an option of chat

Comment: Chats comes up if we have no more than x number of comments

Comment: Sure. Let's hope the chat appears now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194781/discussion-between-ciubotariu-florin-and-learn-aspnet).

Comment: Hi, I used inheritance as you mentioned but now I have discriminator column in my Customer Profile table with distance as null. Is there a way to not add that?