# how to get the request_id from the below json string in C#

Tags: c#, json

Please help, I'm stuck with this

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
     var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
     Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

output :

```
{
    "request_number":"REQ0010201",
    "request_id":"b1c8ba46db3ffa807ea0f4e9bf9619ca",
    "sys_id":"35c8ba46db3ffa807ea0f4e9bf9619ca"
}
```

But I want output as only `request_id` to be printed  : `b1c8ba46db3ffa807ea0f4e9bf9619ca`

Comment: You can refer to this to understand JSON: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/9910/getting-started-json-with-c-sharp#t=201707081329500296074

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Answer (score 0):

if the return data is a json you can two options:

1. Using substring and indexof in a string for search the data after request_id":"
2. Serealize the json into a class and use in a class. For this you could use the classes of microsoft or newtonsoft . I prefer this option

[see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260631/convert-json-into-class-object-in-c-sharp)

Hope I help you

Comment: Thanks for the reply I'm not that much expert in C# can you please give an example code ??

Answer (score 0):

create a class like this:

```
public class myresultclass
{
    public string request_number {get;set;}
    public string request_id {get;set;}
    public string sys_id {get;set;}
}
```

then you chango your function so:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.IO;

public string mymethod()
{

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(result)))  
        {  
            // Deserialization from JSON  
            DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(myresultclass));  
        myresultclass obj = (myresultclass)deserializer.ReadObject(ms);  

        }

            Console.WriteLine(result);

        Console.WriteLine(myresultclass.request_id);
    }
}
```

Note: I write this with notepad if doesn't work get me the error :)

Comment: or can you please give me a simple regex for finding only sys_id from that output.

Comment: for find sys_id: ^(.*?(\bsys_id\b)[^$]*)$

Answer (score 0):

You can easy do it via [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
     var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
     var jObject = JObject.Parse(result);
     var value = (string)jObject["request_id"];
     Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Comment: This didn't worked not returning any value .                                                
       var value = (string)jObject["request_id"];
     Console.WriteLine(value);   //value is null

Answer (score 0):

if You Are Sure That The Request Id Will Always By The Second Attr in The Json Object Then You Can Do Some String Manipulation 
`string.Split(',')` Will Return Array Of Strings Split By The Comma , Now We Know That The Request Id Is The Second Eelment In This Array So `string.Split(',')[1]` Should return The Following String `"request_id":"b1c8ba46db3ffa807ea0f4e9bf9619ca"`

if U Chain Another Split But this Time With Colon and Got The Second Member Of The Out Put Array It Will Be The Id Value `string.Split(':')[1]`

If You Don't Want The Quotation Mark You Can Do `String.Replace("\"",string.Empty)`

So Your Code Should be 
 `JsonObject.Split(',')[1].Split(':')[1].Replace("\"",string.Empty)`

You Could Split By The Colon From The First Time But I Want To Explain More

if You Don't Like That You Can Use NewtonSoft.Json Package To Deserialize The Json Object To Previously Created R