# Map JsonObject to class json

Tags: c#, json

I m trying to populate class object from excel.I received values in json which i m deserializing but i dont want to get List
because in handler class there is function that is of type policy how i can map PolicyNew to class object without List.

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);                    
var policynew = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PolicyNew>>(json);
Policy policy = Handler.GeneratePolicy(policynew);

//Handler.cs
Handler.GeneratePolicy(PolicyNew policynew)
{
}
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of your json ? Besides, this might help :https://stackoverflow.com/a/48023576/4180382

Comment: Json is coming from 
    var query =
    from DbDataRecord row in rdr
    select new
    {
    policynumber=row[0];
    //-------
    };

Comment: it depends on your JSON object if it is an array so it must be mapped to list, if it is only an object you don't use List<>.you can provide example for your json object which will make your question more clear

Comment: [{\"Carrier\":\"text\",\"PolicyNumber\":\"AB00012345\",\"Transac\":\"XYZ\",....  @ Hany Habib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your jsonstring contains an array, you have to deserialize to some sort of List/Array. If you know, you will only need a single element of that list (or you know, that list only contains one element) you can just take the first element of the resulting list.

```
var policynew = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PolicyNew>>(json).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you have control over the generation of the json string, you could change the serialization and not create an array `[{"p1": 3, ...}]` but a single object `{"p1": 3, ...}`