# Json String parsing C# Row and Column

Tags: c#, json

I am Getting Following JSON String from Web service
Want to READ JSON String in ROW and Columns via C# in for loop 
I AM new in C# Object codeing if any Example for below Json String will be more Help full

---

```
[{"_id":"1-1","awid":"1","officeid":"1","prname":"ABCD","prfhname":"Chevy","Ano":"555"},
{"_id":"1-2","awid":"1","officeid":"1","prname":"bheegi","prfhname":"Henry","Ano":"6555"}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp)

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Start with https://stackoverflow.com/a/48023576/4180382

Comment: I AM new in C# Object codeing if any Example for given Json String will be more Help full

Comment: You can deserialize the data into `Dictionary<string, string>` and then iterating over it, will simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create the model. Than you can use for example `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>` method of `Newtonsoft.Json`  to deserialize your json.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = "[{\"_id\":\"1 - 1\",\"awid\":\"1\",\"officeid\":\"1\",\"prname\":\"ABCD\",\"prfhname\":\"Chevy\",\"Ano\":\"555\"},{ \"_id\":\"1-2\",\"awid\":\"1\",\"officeid\":\"1\",\"prname\":\"bheegi\",\"prfhname\":\"Henry\",\"Ano\":\"6555\"}]";
    var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message[]>(json);

    // To see the output (using the for loop as you like ) use this:
    for (int i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("_id: " + message[i]._id);
        Console.WriteLine("awid: " + message[i].awid);
        Console.WriteLine("officeid: " + message[i].officeid);
        Console.WriteLine("prname: " + message[i].prname);
        Console.WriteLine("prfhname: " + message[i].prfhname);
        Console.WriteLine("Ano: " + message[i].Ano);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.Read();
}

class Message
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string awid { get; set; }
    public string officeid { get; set; }
    public string prname { get; set; }
    public string prfhname { get; set; }
    public string Ano { get; set; }
}
```

**Output:**

```
_id: 1 - 1
awid: 1
officeid: 1
prname: ABCD
prfhname: Chevy
Ano: 555

_id: 1-2
awid: 1
officeid: 1
prname: bheegi
prfhname: Henry
Ano: 6555
```