# Extract value for key from json c#

Tags: c#, json, assert

I have the following Json (is a file attached to the project):

```
{
  "Errors": {
    "NoCountry": {
      "MSG": "The CountryCode field is required.",
      "Description": "Error encountered when Country parameter is missing from the request"
    },
    "NoLOI": {
      "MSG": "Validation failed: \r\n -- LengthOfInterview cannot be empty"
      "Description": "Error encountered when LOI parameter is missing from the request"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to extract the values for e.g. Errors.NoCompletes.MSG in order to use it in an assert to compare it with an output that i get from the API.
Till now i tried to create a dictionary that looks like this:

```
public class ErrorsDictionary
{
  public string MSG;
  public string Description;
}

public class DicRoot
{
    public Dictionary<string, ErrorsDictionary> Errors { set; get; }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
DicRoot Json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DicRoot>(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\users\banu_\source\repos\TestJsonLib\TestJsonLib\Json\ErrorMSG.json"));
foreach (var f in Json.Errors)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Nume={0} Mesaj={1} Description={2}",f.Key, f.Value.MSG, f.Value.Description);
}
```

The problem is that i cannot figure out, how can i extract a specific value, like what i said above for Errors.NoLOI.MSG, in order to be able to use it in an assert like Assert.Equals(ex, MyParam);

Comment: Start with https://stackoverflow.com/a/48023576/4180382

Comment: I'm under the impression that a closing double quotation mark is missing for the value of the scond MSG ?

Comment: I think also the comma is missing after that @OleEHDufour noticed

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. If you've got a dictionary and you know the key you want to look up, just use `TryGetValue` or the indexer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are asking for is this?

```
DicRoot dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DicRoot>(File.ReadAllText("foo.json"));
string msg = dict["NoLOI"].MSG;
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed, only mention is that it should be:
     string msg = dict.Errors["NoLOI"].MSG;

Answer (score 1):

You can also use JsonPath, anonymous types and string interpolation if you like:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

var errors = obj
    .SelectTokens("$.Errors.*")
    .ToDictionary(
        e => ((JProperty)e.Parent).Name,
        e => new { Msg = e["MSG"], Descr = e["Description"] });

foreach (var e in errors)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Nume={e.Key} Mesaj={e.Value.Msg} Description={e.Value.Descr}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this looks like a bit working around. However, it's working.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{\"Errors\": {\"NoCountry\": {\"MSG\": \"The CountryCode field is required.\",\"Description\": \"Error encountered when Country parameter is missing from the request\"},\"NoLOI\": {\"MSG\": \"Validation failed: \r\n -- LengthOfInterview cannot be empty\", \"Description\": \"Error encountered when LOI parameter is missing from the request\"},}}";

        var Json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorsClass>(json);
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, ErrorsDictionary>>(Json.Errors.ToString());

        foreach (var f in obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nume={0} Mesaj={1} Description={2}", f.Key, f.Value.MSG, f.Value.Description);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class ErrorsDictionary
{
    public string MSG { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class DicRoot
{
    public Dictionary<string, ErrorsDictionary> ErrorsDic { set; get; }
}

class ErrorsClass
{
    public object Errors { get; set; }
}
```

**Output:**

`Nume=NoCountry Mesaj=The CountryCode field is required. Description=Error encountered when Country parameter is missing from the request
Nume=NoLOI Mesaj=Validation failed:
 -- LengthOfInterview cannot be empty Description=Error encountered when LOI parameter is missing from the request`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newtonsoft.json NuGet. Try this

```
var files = JObject.Parse(YourJson);
var recList = files.SelectTokens("$..Errors").ToList();
foreach (JProperty prop in recList.Children())
{
    string key = prop.Name.ToString();
    string value = prop.Value.ToString();
    //Do your stuffs here
}
```