# c# Deserialize unlabelled JSON array

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am attempting to deserialize a piece of JSON with a specific structure like so:

```
{  
    "label1": "value1",  
    "label2": [  
        [  
            [  
                "concept_id_1",  
                "concept_1"  
            ],  
            score_1  
        ],  
        [  
            [  
                "concept_id_2",  
                "concept_2"  
            ],  
            score_2  
        ],  
        ……  
    ],  
    "label3": "value3",  
    "label4": "value4"  
}
```

For what it's worth, the scores are floats and everything else is a string. The number of returned concepts under "label2" is variable.

I'm attempting to deserialize it using JSON.net. The only content I actually care about is the inside nest of arrays labelled "label2", however the lack of labels inside the arrays is blocking me at every turn.

I've tried a variety of approaches, but the most successful so far seems to be this:

```
public class Parsed_JSON {
    public string label1 { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Full_Result> label2 { get; set; }
    public string label3 { get; set; }
    public string label4 { get; set; }
}

public class Full_Result {
    public IList<string> values { get; set; }
    public float score { get; set; }
}

Parsed_JSON result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parsed_JSON>(JSON);
```

However this is failing with the error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'JSON_Parsing+Full_Result' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Ultimately I'll be looking to iterate through the contents of label2 so that I can build a DataTable of them like so:

```
concept_id_1   concept_1   score_1  
concept_id_2   concept_2   score_2
```

How can I deserialize this JSON?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48023576/4180382

Comment: This: `[  
                "concept_id_1",  
                "concept_1"  
            ],  
            score_1  ` is not the class **Full_Result** that you have described, it is an array of different types

Comment: @MarkiianBenovskyi Thank you, are you able to suggest how I can modify the Parsed_JSON class appropriately?

Comment: @OleEHDufour Thank you, that looks really useful, but unfortunately I'm not able to use Visual Studio (long story)

Comment: You'll need a custom creation converter: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomCreationConverter.htm or https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Comment: I can suggest you to use dynamic objects for that https://stackoverflow.com/a/9326146/4697963

Comment: You can use your current typed data model if you include `ObjectToArrayConverter<Full_Result>` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39462464/3744182) to [C# JSON.NET - Deserialize response that uses an unusual data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39461518/3744182).  You'll need to mark the properties of `Full_Result` with `[JsonProperty(Order = N)]` attributes.

Comment: @MarkiianBenovskyi Thanks, although I didn't use dynamic objects in the end your suggestion did lead me to a working approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) `ObjectToArrayConverter<Full_Result>` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39462464/3744182) to *[C# JSON.NET - Deserialize response that uses an unusual data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39461518/3744182)* to deserialize your JSON into your existing typed data model.  Modify `Full_Result` as follows:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectToArrayConverter<Full_Result>))]
public class Full_Result 
{
    [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
    public IList<string> values { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
    public float score { get; set; }
}
```

And you will now be able to deserialize as follows:

```
Parsed_JSON result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parsed_JSON>(JSON);
```

Notes:

- `ObjectToArrayConverter<T>` works by mapping the serializable members of `T` to an array, where the array sequence is defined by the value of the [`JsonPropertyAttribute.Order`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_Order.htm) attribute applied to each member.  [Data contract attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-member-order) with [`DataMemberAttribute.Order`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.order?view=netframework-4.7.2) set could be used instead, if you prefer.
- In your JSON the "score" values are not actually numbers:

  ```
  score_1
  score_2
  ```

  I am assuming that this is a typo in the question and that these values are in fact well-formed numbers as defined by the [JSON standard](http://json.org/).

Sample fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KtUQsI).

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect for me!