# Best way to parse a string to recognisable data structure

Tags: c#, json, string, parsing, time-series

I have some data in the following format. There's a uuid with timeseries reading, each tuple representing a timestamp and value.

```
"[{\"uuid\": \"3c24a849-3355-5b28-bf83-1e93c36eea75\", \"Readings\": [[1541524171000.0, 22.700000762939453], [1541531370000.0, 22.600000381469727], [1541577227000.0, 21.700000762939453], [1541578016000.0, 21.899999618530273], [1541578322000.0, 22.100000381469727], [1541580122000.0, 22.0]]}]"
```

This is a response from a rest service that's meant to return json. I went ahead and did

```
public class DataReading
{
    public string uuid { get; set; }
    public string readings { get; set; }
}
```

imported Newtonsoft.Json and did

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataReading>>(thereturnstring);
```

I'm getting an error

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path '[0].Readings', line 1, position 63.'
```

Any insight? Line 1 position 63 seems to be the 'n' in Readings.
How do I convert this to anything meaningful?

Comment: Your JSON has an array, not a string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48023576/4180382

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your class from:

```
public class DataReading
{
    public string uuid { get; set; }
    public string readings { get; set; }
}
```

to

```
public class DataReading
{
    public string uuid { get; set; }
    public double[][] readings { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can Deserialize it like:

```
string jsonString = "[{\"uuid\": \"3c24a849-3355-5b28-bf83-1e93c36eea75\", \"Readings\": [[1541524171000.0, 22.700000762939453], [1541531370000.0, 22.600000381469727], [1541577227000.0, 21.700000762939453], [1541578016000.0, 21.899999618530273], [1541578322000.0, 22.100000381469727], [1541580122000.0, 22.0]]}]";
var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataReading[]>(jsonString);
```

[**Live Demo**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mikRkP)

Comment: That's not a string array.

Comment: yes I saw that, I was wrong, and its array of array.

Comment: It worked, thanks. I'll accept the answer when it allows me. :)