# Retrive price from JSON structure: C# World Trading Data API

Tags: c#, json, json.net, finance

1st time using World Trading data and JSONs in general. I am trying to retrieve the current price of a stock in C#

```
 using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    static void get_stock_price()
    {
        string json;
        using (var web = new WebClient())
        {
            var url = $" https://www.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/stock?symbol=AAPL,MSFT,HSBA.L&api_token=Io4R1hqd0rLONZcMp6tJgupqjVEyO0pVJAo65a6QlJjHjVBpEyt5nm73zZ5X";
            json = web.DownloadString(url);
            //How can I extract the price from the above?
        }
```

According to the developers documentation: the object returns a json structured like below:

```
{
"symbols_requested": 1,
"symbols_returned": 1,
"data": [
    {
        "symbol": "AAPL",
        "name": "Apple Inc.",
        "price": "174.33",
        "currency": "USD",
        "price_open": "173.71",
        "day_high": "175.30",
        "day_low": "173.17",
        "52_week_high": "233.47",
        "52_week_low": "142.00",
        "day_change": "0.10",
        "change_pct": "0.06",
        "close_yesterday": "174.23",
        "market_cap": "822014771033",
        "volume": "3171",
        "volume_avg": "28795902",
        "shares": "4715280000",
        "stock_exchange_long": "NASDAQ Stock Exchange",
        "stock_exchange_short": "NASDAQ",
        "timezone": "EST",
        "timezone_name": "America/New_York",
        "gmt_offset": "-18000",
        "last_trade_time": "2019-02-26 16:00:01"
    }
]
}
```

This is the site documentation: https://www.worldtradingdata.com/documentation#stock-and-index-real-time

This is the HTTP request link:
https://www.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/stock?symbol=AAPL,MSFT,HSBA.L&api_token=Io4R1hqd0rLONZcMp6tJgupqjVEyO0pVJAo65a6QlJjHjVBpEyt5nm73zZ5X

Could someone please guide me how to extract the price from the object?

Comment: Did you even try to Google a solution to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load JSON text into class object in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48023576/34092)

Comment: I am stuck mostly on the fact I don't understand the line on davidG's link:

dynamic stuff = JObject.Parse("{ 'Name': 'Jon Smith', 'Address': { 'City': 'New York', 'State': 'NY' }, 'Age': 42 }");

I can't seem to figure out how to replace it with structure of my json

Answer (score 2):

You can use Newtonsoft.Json library to get price like this:

```
var trade = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
                var price = trade.data[0].price.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, this is exactly what I am after!