# strong typed classes for JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-core, formio

I've run into a scenario where I would get lot of **form.io** **Javasrcipt** based **JSON** objects to come to a **Controller**. How could I **generate C# classes** so that they could be **strong typed**?

JavaScript Classes:

```
export default class SomeComponent {
static schema(...sources) {
return _.merge({
  /**
   * Determines if this component provides an input.
   */
  input: true,

  /**
   * The data key for this component (how the data is stored in the database).
   */
  key: '',

  ...

  }
```

JSON object that goes to the controller:

```
{
 "input":true,
  "key":"inputElement"
}
```

The controller that receives:

```
  public IActionResult Receiver(???) // strongly typed for many kinds of JSON?
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to convert the object to C# at run-time? or it will be like any other controller action e.g 

public IActionResult Receiver(Product product) // strongly typed for many kinds of JSON?
    {
        return View();
    }

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this John: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260631/load-json-text-into-class-object-in-c-sharp

Comment: @IkramShah I'll have the controller action with strongly typed for many kinds of JSON in the noraml way. I basically have many objects to convert into strong typed classes.

Comment: If you're using visual studio 2017 then here is your answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48023576/1526972

Comment: @IkramShah I've come across this option earlier but I'm looking for a better way than pasting each JSON object manually.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for some sort of automated solution. None exists. You'll need to add classes manually which model your JSON. There's ways to automate that particular part: JSON to C# class. However, you'll still need to go class by class and update your controller actions accordingly to accept those classes.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yes, I'm looking for JSON to C# class generation part.

Comment: See the answer @IkramShah linked to.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Well, automation isn't presented in the solutions. Copy + Paste options are available.

Comment: Again. The only part you can automate is the process of turning a JSON object into a C# class. Everything else is only you, including potentially creating the physical files in your project, etc. It saves you the time of having to manually write out properties by hand, but there is no *true* automation for something like this.