# DeserializeObject in .net only for specific properties

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I have a class with 2 properties, but I'm getting a JSON object with a few properties that I don't need. I want to use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject but I'm getting an error because my class doesn't correspond to the JSON object.
Do you have any code example on how to solve this using JsonConvert?
**I want to avoid using JObject.Parse**

How I tried to use JsonConvert:

```
 var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LinkedInUser>(await GetData(token));
```

GetData returns the JSON object

LinkedInUseris the class that contains the properties that exist in the JSON object that i need

edit:
I'm trying to get data from linkedin

This is the Json object:

```
   {
   "id":"REDACTED",
   "firstName":{
      "localized":{
         "en_US":"Tina"
      },
      "preferredLocale":{
         "country":"US",
         "language":"en"
      }
   },
   "lastName":{
      "localized":{
         "en_US":"Belcher"
      },
      "preferredLocale":{
         "country":"US",
         "language":"en"
      }
   },
    "profilePicture": {
        "displayImage": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:B54328XZFfe2134zTyq"
    }
}
```

And this is LinkedInUser object:

```
namespace project.DTOs.Models
{
    public class LinkedInUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set;}
        public string LastName { get; set; }  
    }
}
```

I can't convert the JSON to LinkedInUser using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject this way, does anyone know a way to do it easily?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It should work right out of the box. Here is an [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QCsUJ6)

Comment: Unclear what your issue is, as Json.Net should deal with that easily. Most likely it doesn't correspond for a different reason. Please show your class definition and the full JSON

Comment: If you're looking to convert a json string to a C# object : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48023576/4180382

Comment: @Fabjan thanks! not sure how it's gonna work though because i need to drill down the json, please see example above, I need to get this object: firstName.localized.en_US

Answer (score 1):

I can only offer you this solution in one line using modernized LinkedInUser

```
LinkedInUser person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LinkedInUser>(json);
```

or in two lines, using your LinkedInUser

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
LinkedInUser user = new LinkedInUser { FirstName=data.FirstName, LastName=data.LastName};
```

output

```
FirstName   Tina
LastName    Belcher
```

but you will not need any extra classes at all if you use Parse

```
    var o =JObject.Parse(json);

    var linkedInUser = new LinkedInUser {
         FirstName=  (string) o["firstName"]["localized"]["en_US"],
         LastName= (string) o["lastName"]["localized"]["en_US"]
         };
```

classes

```
public class Data:BaseData
// or
public class LinkedInUser:BaseData
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _stFirstName == null ? null : _stFirstName.Localized.EnUs; }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _stLastName == null ? null : _stLastName.Localized.EnUs; }
    }
}


public partial class BaseData
{
    protected StName _stFirstName { get; set; }
    protected StName _stLastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("firstName")]
    public StName StFirstName
    {
        set { _stFirstName = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty("lastName")]
    public StName StLastName
    {
        set { _stLastName = value; }
    }
}

public partial class StName
{
    [JsonProperty("localized")]
    public Localized Localized { get; set; }
}

public partial class Localized
{
    [JsonProperty("en_US")]
    public string EnUs { get; set; }
}
```