# C# Json extract a list of values from a Json list or array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, list

I want to extract the values from "scanEvents" list or array. Each scanEvent has a date, eventtype, eventdescrption, derivedstatus, etc...

I have used several methods, such as this one below, but so far I am unable to extract the values for each "scanEvent"

```
 var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strFedExJSON);
            
            var scanevents = data["scanEvents"];

            var output = scanevents.Children<JProperty>()
                                 .Select(prop => prop.Value.ToObject<Scanevent>())
                                 .ToList();

           foreach (var x in output)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += output + Environment.NewLine;
            }
```

I want to end up with this kind of output below:

```
 "date": "2021-12-22T15:14:00-10:00", "eventDescription": "Delivered", "city": "HILO",    "stateOrProvinceCode": "HI", "countryCode": "US", "locationType": "DELIVERY_LOCATION",  "derivedStatus": "Delivered"


 "date": "2021-12-22T14:40:00-10:00", "eventDescription": "On FedEx vehicle for delivery", "city": "HILO","stateOrProvinceCode": "HI","countryCode": "US",    "locationType": "VEHICLE", "derivedStatus": "In transit"  


 "date": "2021-12-22T14:37:00-10:00","eventDescription": "At local FedEx facility","city":  "countryCode": "US","HILO",  "locationType": "DESTINATION_FEDEX_FACILITY",  "derivedStatus": "In transit"
```

How do you extract the values (date, eventDescription, derivedstatus) for each event in  "scanEvents" list below? This one seems to be buried under several types or objects.

```
{
    "transactionId": "44d2c2a9-1204-4ff7-94f3-ae8699257f77",
    "output": {
        "completeTrackResults": [
            {
                "trackingNumber": "673247499414",
                "trackResults": [
                    {
                        "trackingNumberInfo": {
                            "trackingNumber": "673247499414",
                            "trackingNumberUniqueId": "2459570000~673247499414~FX",
                            "carrierCode": "FDXE"
                        },
                        "additionalTrackingInfo": {
                            "nickname": "",
                            "packageIdentifiers": [
                                {
                                    "type": "DEPARTMENT",
                                    "values": [
                                        "32 MQ"
                                    ],
                                    "trackingNumberUniqueId": "",
                                    "carrierCode": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "SHIPPER_REFERENCE",
                                    "values": [
                                        "6033245/O956871"
                                    ],
                                    "trackingNumberUniqueId": "",
                                    "carrierCode": ""
                                }
                            ],
                            "hasAssociatedShipments": false
                        },
                        "shipperInformation": {
                            "contact": {},
                            "address": {
                                "city": "MIRA LOMA",
                                "stateOrProvinceCode": "CA",
                                "countryCode": "US",
                                "residential": false,
                                "countryName": "United States"
                            }
                        },
                        "recipientInformation": {
                            "contact": {},
                            "address": {
                                "city": "HILO",
                                "stateOrProvinceCode": "HI",
                                "countryCode": "US",
                                "residential": false,
                                "countryName": "United States"
                            }
                        },
                        "latestStatusDetail": {
                            "code": "DL",
                            "derivedCode": "DL",
                            "statusByLocale": "Delivered",
                            "description": "Delivered",
                            "scanLocation": {
                                "city": "HILO",
                                "stateOrProvinceCode": "HI",
                                "countryCode": "US",
                                "residential": false,
                                "countryName": "United States"
                            }
                        },
                        "dateAndTimes": [
                            {
                                "type": "ACTUAL_DELIVERY",
                                "dateTime": "2021-12-22T15:14:00-10:00"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "ACTUAL_PICKUP",
                                "dateTime": "2021-12-21T18:12:00-08:00"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "SHIP",
                                "dateTime": "2021-12-21T00:00:00-06:00"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "ACTUAL_TENDER",
                                "dateTime": "2021-12-21T18:14:00-08:00"
                            }
                        ],
                        "availableImages": [
                            {
                                "type": "SIGNATURE_PROOF_OF_DELIVERY"
                            }
                        ],
                        "specialHandlings": [
                            {
                                "type": "DELIVER_WEEKDAY",
                                "description": "Deliver Weekday",
                                "paymentType": "OTHER"
                            }
                        ],
                        "packageDetails": {
                            "packagingDescription": {
                                "type": "YOUR_PACKAGING",
                                "description": "Your Packaging"
                            },
                            "sequenceNumber": "1",
                            "count": "1",
                            "weightAndDimensions": {
                                "weight": [
                                    {
                                        "value": "10.0",
                                        "unit": "LB"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "4.54",
                                        "unit": "KG"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "dimensions": [
                                    {
                                        "length": 20,
                                        "width": 12,
                                        "height": 13,
                                        "units": "IN"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "length": 50,
                                        "width": 30,
                                        "height": 33,
                                        "units": "CM"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "packageContent": []
                        },
                        "shipmentDetails": {
                            "possessionStatus": true,
                            "weight": [
                                {
                                    "value": "10.0",
                                    "unit": "LB"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "4.54",
                                    "unit": "KG"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "scanEvents": [
                            {
                                "date": "2021-12-22T15:14:00-10:00",
                                "eventType": "DL",
                                "eventDescription": "Delivered",
                                "exceptionCode": "",
                                "exceptionDescription": "",
                                "scanLocation": {
                                    "streetLines": [
                                        ""
                                    ],
                                    "city": "HILO",
                                    "stateOrProvinceCode": "HI",
                                    "postalCode": "96720",
                                    "countryCode": "US",
                                    "residential": false,
                                    "countryName": "United States"
                                },
                                "locationId": "ITOA",
                                "locationType": "DELIVERY_LOCATION",
                                "derivedStatusCode": "DL",
                                "derivedStatus": "Delivered"
                            },
                            {
                                "date": "2021-12-22T14:40:00-10:00",
                                "eventType": "OD",
                                "eventDescription": "On FedEx vehicle for delivery",
                                "exceptionCode": "",
                                "exceptionDescription": "",
                                "scanLocation": {
                                    "streetLines": [
                                        ""
                                    ],
                                    "city": "HILO",
                                    "stateOrProvinceCode": "HI",
                                    "postalCode": "96720",
                                    "countryCode": "US",
                                    "residential": false,
                                    "countryName": "United States"
                                },
                                "locationId": "ITOA",
                                "locationType": "VEHICLE",
                                "derivedStatusCode": "IT",
                                "derivedStatus": "In transit"
                            },
                            {
                                "date": "2021-12-22T14:37:00-10:00",
                                "eventType": "AR",
                                "eventDescription": "At local FedEx facility",
                                "exceptionCode": "",
                                "exceptionDescription": "",
                                "scanLocation": {
                                    "streetLines": [
                                        ""
                                    ],
                                    "city": "HILO",
                                    "stateOrProvinceCode": "HI",
                                    "postalCode": "96720",
                                    "countryCode": "US",
                                    "residential": false,
                                    "countryName": "United States"
                                },
                                "locationId": "ITOA",
                                "locationType": "DESTINATION_FEDEX_FACILITY",
                                "derivedStatusCode": "IT",
                                "derivedStatus": "In transit"
                            },
                            {
                                "date": "2021-12-22T07:35:00-10:00",
                                "eventType": "AR",
                                "eventDescription": "At destination sort facility",
                                "exceptionCode": "",
                                "exceptionDescription": "",
                                "scanLocation": {
                                    "streetLines": [
                                        ""
                                    ],
                                    "city": "HONOLULU",
                                    "stateOrProvinceCode": "HI",
                                    "postalCode": "96819",
                                    "countryCode": "US",
                                    "residential": false,
                                    "countryName": "United States"
                                },
                                "locationId": "HNLR",
                                "locationType": "SORT_FACILITY",
                                "derivedStatusCode": "IT",
                                "derivedStatus": "In transit"
                            },
                            {
                                "date": "2021-12-22T04:21:00-08:00",
                                "eventType": "DP",
                                "eventDescription": "Departed FedEx hub",
                                "exceptionCode": "",
                                "exceptionDescription": "",
                                "scanLocation": {
                                    "streetLines": [
                                        ""
                                    ],
                                    "city": "OAKLAND",
                                    "stateOrProvinceCode": "CA",
                                    "postalCode": "94621",
                                    "countryCode": "US",
                                    "residential": false,
                                    "countryName": "United States"
                                },
                                "locationId": "OAKH",
                                "locationType": "FEDEX_FACILITY",
                                "derivedStatusCode": "IT",
                                "derivedStatus": "In transit"
                            },
                            {
                                "date": "2021-12-21T23:27:00-08:00",
                                "eventType": "AR",
                                "eventDescription": "Arrived at FedEx hub",
                                "exceptionCode": "",
                                "exceptionDescription": "",
                                "scanLocation": {
                                    "streetLines": [
                                        ""
                                    ],
                                    "city": "OAKLAND",
                                    "stateOrProvinceCode": "CA",
                                    "postalCode": "94621",
                                    "countryCode": "US",
                                    "residential": false,
                                    "countryName": "United States"
                                },
                                "locationId": "OAKH",
                                "locationType": "FEDEX_FACILITY",
                                "derivedStatusCode": "IT",
                                "derivedStatus": "In transit"
                            },
                            {
                                "date": "2021-12-21T19:13:00-08:00",
                                "eventType": "DP",
                                "eventDescription": "Left FedEx origin facility",
                                "exceptionCode": "",
                                "exceptionDescription": "",
                                "scanLocation": {
                                    "streetLines": [
                                        ""
                                    ],
                                    "city": "ONTARIO",
                                    "stateOrProvinceCode": "CA",
                                    "postalCode": "91761",
                                    "countryCode": "US",
                                    "residential": false,
                                    "countryName": "United States"
                                },
                                "locationId": "ONTA",
                                "locationType": "ORIGIN_FEDEX_FACILITY",
                                "derivedStatusCode": "IT",
                                "derivedStatus": "In transit"
                            },
                            {
                                "date": "2021-12-21T18:12:00-08:00",
                                "eventType": "PU",
                                "eventDescription": "Picked up",
                                "exceptionCode": "",
                                "exceptionDescription": "",
                                "scanLocation": {
                                    "streetLines": [
                                        ""
                                    ],
                                    "city": "ONTARIO",
                                    "stateOrProvinceCode": "CA",
                                    "postalCode": "91761",
                                    "countryCode": "US",
                                    "residential": false,
                                    "countryName": "United States"
                                },
                                "locationId": "ONTA",
                                "locationType": "PICKUP_LOCATION",
                                "derivedStatusCode": "PU",
                                "derivedStatus": "Picked up"
                            },
                            {
                                "date": "2021-12-21T16:55:06-06:00",
                                "eventType": "OC",
                                "eventDescription": "Shipment information sent to FedEx",
                                "exceptionCode": "",
                                "exceptionDescription": "",
                                "scanLocation": {
                                    "streetLines": [
                                        ""
                                    ],
                                    "residential": false
                                },
                                "locationType": "CUSTOMER",
                                "derivedStatusCode": "IN",
                                "derivedStatus": "Initiated"
                            }
                        ],
                        "availableNotifications": [
                            "ON_DELIVERY"
                        ],
                        "deliveryDetails": {
                            "actualDeliveryAddress": {
                                "city": "HILO",
                                "stateOrProvinceCode": "HI",
                                "countryCode": "US",
                                "residential": false,
                                "countryName": "United States"
                            },
                            "locationType": "SHIPPING_RECEIVING",
                            "locationDescription": "Shipping/Receiving",
                            "deliveryAttempts": "0",
                            "receivedByName": "L.WEAVER",
                            "deliveryOptionEligibilityDetails": [
                                {
                                    "option": "INDIRECT_SIGNATURE_RELEASE",
                                    "eligibility": "INELIGIBLE"
                                },
                                {
                                    "option": "REDIRECT_TO_HOLD_AT_LOCATION",
                                    "eligibility": "INELIGIBLE"
                                },
                                {
                                    "option": "REROUTE",
                                    "eligibility": "INELIGIBLE"
                                },
                                {
                                    "option": "RESCHEDULE",
                                    "eligibility": "INELIGIBLE"
                                },
                                {
                                    "option": "RETURN_TO_SHIPPER",
                                    "eligibility": "INELIGIBLE"
                                },
                                {
                                    "option": "DISPUTE_DELIVERY",
                                    "eligibility": "INELIGIBLE"
                                },
                                {
                                    "option": "SUPPLEMENT_ADDRESS",
                                    "eligibility": "INELIGIBLE"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "originLocation": {
                            "locationContactAndAddress": {
                                "address": {
                                    "city": "ONTARIO",
                                    "stateOrProvinceCode": "CA",
                                    "countryCode": "US",
                                    "residential": false,
                                    "countryName": "United States"
                                }
                            },
                            "locationId": "ONTA"
                        },
                        "destinationLocation": {
                            "locationContactAndAddress": {
                                "address": {
                                    "city": "HILO",
                                    "stateOrProvinceCode": "HI",
                                    "countryCode": "US",
                                    "residential": false,
                                    "countryName": "United States"
                                }
                            },
                            "locationType": ""
                        },
                        "lastUpdatedDestinationAddress": {
                            "city": "HILO",
                            "stateOrProvinceCode": "HI",
                            "countryCode": "US",
                            "residential": false,
                            "countryName": "United States"
                        },
                        "serviceDetail": {
                            "type": "PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT",
                            "description": "FedEx Priority Overnight",
                            "shortDescription": "PO"
                        },
                        "standardTransitTimeWindow": {
                            "window": {
                                "ends": "2021-12-22T17:00:00-10:00"
                            }
                        },
                        "estimatedDeliveryTimeWindow": {
                            "window": {}
                        },
                        "goodsClassificationCode": "",
                        "returnDetail": {}
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks to me that you could have multiple scanEvents when the json contains multiple trackResults. So no clear path to that. And your output at the end should contain the trackingNumber so you know where the event belongs to in that case. What i would do would be to create real classes to serialize the json into (use a json to class converter). That is easier to understand in code and you have an easier time navigation through the class tree and creation a meaningfull output string from that.

Comment: You could consider creating a class automatically which enables you to loop through its stronly typed properties; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48023576/4180382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(strFedExJSON); 

 var scanEventsJson= jsonObject["output"]["completeTrackResults"][0]["trackResults"][0] ["scanEvents"].ToString();
```

output

```
  {
    "date": "2021-12-22T21:44:00-03:30",
    "eventType": "DL",
    "eventDescription": "Delivered",
    "exceptionCode": "",
    "exceptionDescription": "",
    "scanLocation": {
      "streetLines": [
        ""
      ],
      "city": "HILO",
      "stateOrProvinceCode": "HI",
      "postalCode": "96720",
      "countryCode": "US",
      "residential": false,
      "countryName": "United States"
    },
    "locationId": "ITOA",
    "locationType": "DELIVERY_LOCATION",
    "derivedStatusCode": "DL",
    "derivedStatus": "Delivered"
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-12-22T21:10:00-03:30",
    "eventType": "OD",
    "eventDescription": "On FedEx vehicle for delivery",
    "exceptionCode": "",
    "exceptionDescription": "",
    "scanLocation": {
      "streetLines": [
        ""
      ],
      "city": "HILO",
      "stateOrProvinceCode": "HI",
      "postalCode": "96720",
      "countryCode": "US",
      "residential": false,
      "countryName": "United States"
    },
    "locationId": "ITOA",
    "locationType": "VEHICLE",
    "derivedStatusCode": "IT",
    "derivedStatus": "In transit"
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-12-22T21:07:00-03:30",
    "eventType": "AR",
    "eventDescription": "At local FedEx facility",
    "exceptionCode": "",
    "exceptionDescription": "",
    "scanLocation": {
      "streetLines": [
        ""
      ],
      "city": "HILO",
      "stateOrProvinceCode": "HI",
      "postalCode": "96720",
      "countryCode": "US",
      "residential": false,
      "countryName": "United States"
    },
    "locationId": "ITOA",
    "locationType": "DESTINATION_FEDEX_FACILITY",
    "derivedStatusCode": "IT",
    "derivedStatus": "In transit"
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-12-22T14:05:00-03:30",
    "eventType": "AR",
    "eventDescription": "At destination sort facility",
    "exceptionCode": "",
    "exceptionDescription": "",
    "scanLocation": {
      "streetLines": [
        ""
      ],
      "city": "HONOLULU",
      "stateOrProvinceCode": "HI",
      "postalCode": "96819",
      "countryCode": "US",
      "residential": false,
      "countryName": "United States"
    },
    "locationId": "HNLR",
    "locationType": "SORT_FACILITY",
    "derivedStatusCode": "IT",
    "derivedStatus": "In transit"
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-12-22T08:51:00-03:30",
    "eventType": "DP",
    "eventDescription": "Departed FedEx hub",
    "exceptionCode": "",
    "exceptionDescription": "",
    "scanLocation": {
      "streetLines": [
        ""
      ],
      "city": "OAKLAND",
      "stateOrProvinceCode": "CA",
      "postalCode": "94621",
      "countryCode": "US",
      "residential": false,
      "countryName": "United States"
    },
    "locationId": "OAKH",
    "locationType": "FEDEX_FACILITY",
    "derivedStatusCode": "IT",
    "derivedStatus": "In transit"
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-12-22T03:57:00-03:30",
    "eventType": "AR",
    "eventDescription": "Arrived at FedEx hub",
    "exceptionCode": "",
    "exceptionDescription": "",
    "scanLocation": {
      "streetLines": [
        ""
      ],
      "city": "OAKLAND",
      "stateOrProvinceCode": "CA",
      "postalCode": "94621",
      "countryCode": "US",
      "residential": false,
      "countryName": "United States"
    },
    "locationId": "OAKH",
    "locationType": "FEDEX_FACILITY",
    "derivedStatusCode": "IT",
    "derivedStatus": "In transit"
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-12-21T23:43:00-03:30",
    "eventType": "DP",
    "eventDescription": "Left FedEx origin facility",
    "exceptionCode": "",
    "exceptionDescription": "",
    "scanLocation": {
      "streetLines": [
        ""
      ],
      "city": "ONTARIO",
      "stateOrProvinceCode": "CA",
      "postalCode": "91761",
      "countryCode": "US",
      "residential": false,
      "countryName": "United States"
    },
    "locationId": "ONTA",
    "locationType": "ORIGIN_FEDEX_FACILITY",
    "derivedStatusCode": "IT",
    "derivedStatus": "In transit"
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-12-21T22:42:00-03:30",
    "eventType": "PU",
    "eventDescription": "Picked up",
    "exceptionCode": "",
    "exceptionDescription": "",
    "scanLocation": {
      "streetLines": [
        ""
      ],
      "city": "ONTARIO",
      "stateOrProvinceCode": "CA",
      "postalCode": "91761",
      "countryCode": "US",
      "residential": false,
      "countryName": "United States"
    },
    "locationId": "ONTA",
    "locationType": "PICKUP_LOCATION",
    "derivedStatusCode": "PU",
    "derivedStatus": "Picked up"
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-12-21T19:25:06-03:30",
    "eventType": "OC",
    "eventDescription": "Shipment information sent to FedEx",
    "exceptionCode": "",
    "exceptionDescription": "",
    "scanLocation": {
      "streetLines": [
        ""
      ],
      "residential": false
    },
    "locationType": "CUSTOMER",
    "derivedStatusCode": "IN",
    "derivedStatus": "Initiated"
  }
]
```

I can make it in one line if you need , but it would be harder to read.

```
foreach (var completeTrackResult in jsonObject["output"]["completeTrackResults"])
{
    foreach (var trackResult in completeTrackResult["trackResults"])
    {
        foreach (var scanEvent in trackResult["scanEvents"])
        {
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(scanEvent) + "\n\r");
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
{"date":"2021-12-22T21:44:00-03:30","eventType":"DL","eventDescription":"Delivered","exceptionCode":"","exceptionDescription":"","scanLocation":{"streetLines":[""],"city":"HILO","stateOrProvinceCode":"HI","postalCode":"96720","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"},"locationId":"ITOA","locationType":"DELIVERY_LOCATION","derivedStatusCode":"DL","derivedStatus":"Delivered"}

{"date":"2021-12-22T21:10:00-03:30","eventType":"OD","eventDescription":"On FedEx vehicle for delivery","exceptionCode":"","exceptionDescription":"","scanLocation":{"streetLines":[""],"city":"HILO","stateOrProvinceCode":"HI","postalCode":"96720","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"},"locationId":"ITOA","locationType":"VEHICLE","derivedStatusCode":"IT","derivedStatus":"In transit"}

{"date":"2021-12-22T21:07:00-03:30","eventType":"AR","eventDescription":"At local FedEx facility","exceptionCode":"","exceptionDescription":"","scanLocation":{"streetLines":[""],"city":"HILO","stateOrProvinceCode":"HI","postalCode":"96720","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"},"locationId":"ITOA","locationType":"DESTINATION_FEDEX_FACILITY","derivedStatusCode":"IT","derivedStatus":"In transit"}

{"date":"2021-12-22T14:05:00-03:30","eventType":"AR","eventDescription":"At destination sort facility","exceptionCode":"","exceptionDescription":"","scanLocation":{"streetLines":[""],"city":"HONOLULU","stateOrProvinceCode":"HI","postalCode":"96819","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"},"locationId":"HNLR","locationType":"SORT_FACILITY","derivedStatusCode":"IT","derivedStatus":"In transit"}

{"date":"2021-12-22T08:51:00-03:30","eventType":"DP","eventDescription":"Departed FedEx hub","exceptionCode":"","exceptionDescription":"","scanLocation":{"streetLines":[""],"city":"OAKLAND","stateOrProvinceCode":"CA","postalCode":"94621","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"},"locationId":"OAKH","locationType":"FEDEX_FACILITY","derivedStatusCode":"IT","derivedStatus":"In transit"}

{"date":"2021-12-22T03:57:00-03:30","eventType":"AR","eventDescription":"Arrived at FedEx hub","exceptionCode":"","exceptionDescription":"","scanLocation":{"streetLines":[""],"city":"OAKLAND","stateOrProvinceCode":"CA","postalCode":"94621","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"},"locationId":"OAKH","locationType":"FEDEX_FACILITY","derivedStatusCode":"IT","derivedStatus":"In transit"}

{"date":"2021-12-21T23:43:00-03:30","eventType":"DP","eventDescription":"Left FedEx origin facility","exceptionCode":"","exceptionDescription":"","scanLocation":{"streetLines":[""],"city":"ONTARIO","stateOrProvinceCode":"CA","postalCode":"91761","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"},"locationId":"ONTA","locationType":"ORIGIN_FEDEX_FACILITY","derivedStatusCode":"IT","derivedStatus":"In transit"}

{"date":"2021-12-21T22:42:00-03:30","eventType":"PU","eventDescription":"Picked up","exceptionCode":"","exceptionDescription":"","scanLocation":{"streetLines":[""],"city":"ONTARIO","stateOrProvinceCode":"CA","postalCode":"91761","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"},"locationId":"ONTA","locationType":"PICKUP_LOCATION","derivedStatusCode":"PU","derivedStatus":"Picked up"}

{"date":"2021-12-21T19:25:06-03:30","eventType":"OC","eventDescription":"Shipment information sent to FedEx","exceptionCode":"","exceptionDescription":"","scanLocation":{"streetLines":[""],"residential":false},"locationType":"CUSTOMER","derivedStatusCode":"IN","derivedStatus":"Initiated"}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, as others have commented (and my feelings align) whenever we have a reasonably amount of processing to do with some JSON thing, it's easier to parse the JSON to objects and work with the objects. I (personally, no affiliation) head over to https://quicktype.io and paste the JSON in there, to generate a set of classes:

```
// <auto-generated />
//
// To parse this JSON data, add NuGet 'Newtonsoft.Json' then do:
//
//    using HackyTracky;
//
//    var trackyThing = TrackyThing.FromJson(jsonString);

namespace HackyTracky
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class TrackyThing
    {
        [JsonProperty("transactionId")]
        public Guid TransactionId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("output")]
        public Output Output { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Output
    {
        [JsonProperty("completeTrackResults")]
        public CompleteTrackResult[] CompleteTrackResults { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class CompleteTrackResult
    {
        [JsonProperty("trackingNumber")]
        public string TrackingNumber { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("trackResults")]
        public TrackResult[] TrackResults { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class TrackResult
    {
        [JsonProperty("trackingNumberInfo")]
        public TrackingNumberInfo TrackingNumberInfo { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("additionalTrackingInfo")]
        public AdditionalTrackingInfo AdditionalTrackingInfo { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("shipperInformation")]
        public Information ShipperInformation { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("recipientInformation")]
        public Information RecipientInformation { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("latestStatusDetail")]
        public LatestStatusDetail LatestStatusDetail { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("dateAndTimes")]
        public DateAndTime[] DateAndTimes { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("availableImages")]
        public AvailableImage[] AvailableImages { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("specialHandlings")]
        public SpecialHandling[] SpecialHandlings { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("packageDetails")]
        public PackageDetails PackageDetails { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("shipmentDetails")]
        public ShipmentDetails ShipmentDetails { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("scanEvents")]
        public ScanEvent[] ScanEvents { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("availableNotifications")]
        public string[] AvailableNotifications { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("deliveryDetails")]
        public DeliveryDetails DeliveryDetails { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("originLocation")]
        public OriginLocation OriginLocation { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("destinationLocation")]
        public DestinationLocation DestinationLocation { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lastUpdatedDestinationAddress")]
        public LastUpdatedDestinationAddress LastUpdatedDestinationAddress { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("serviceDetail")]
        public ServiceDetail ServiceDetail { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("standardTransitTimeWindow")]
        public StandardTransitTimeWindow StandardTransitTimeWindow { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("estimatedDeliveryTimeWindow")]
        public EstimatedDeliveryTimeWindow EstimatedDeliveryTimeWindow { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("goodsClassificationCode")]
        public string GoodsClassificationCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("returnDetail")]
        public ReturnDetail ReturnDetail { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class AdditionalTrackingInfo
    {
        [JsonProperty("nickname")]
        public string Nickname { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("packageIdentifiers")]
        public PackageIdentifier[] PackageIdentifiers { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("hasAssociatedShipments")]
        public bool HasAssociatedShipments { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class PackageIdentifier
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("values")]
        public string[] Values { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("trackingNumberUniqueId")]
        public string TrackingNumberUniqueId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("carrierCode")]
        public string CarrierCode { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class AvailableImage
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class DateAndTime
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("dateTime")]
        public DateTimeOffset DateTime { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class DeliveryDetails
    {
        [JsonProperty("actualDeliveryAddress")]
        public LastUpdatedDestinationAddress ActualDeliveryAddress { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("locationType")]
        public string LocationType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("locationDescription")]
        public string LocationDescription { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("deliveryAttempts")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long DeliveryAttempts { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("receivedByName")]
        public string ReceivedByName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("deliveryOptionEligibilityDetails")]
        public DeliveryOptionEligibilityDetail[] DeliveryOptionEligibilityDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class LastUpdatedDestinationAddress
    {
        [JsonProperty("city")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("stateOrProvinceCode")]
        public string StateOrProvinceCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("countryCode")]
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("residential")]
        public bool Residential { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("countryName")]
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class DeliveryOptionEligibilityDetail
    {
        [JsonProperty("option")]
        public string Option { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("eligibility")]
        public string Eligibility { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class DestinationLocation
    {
        [JsonProperty("locationContactAndAddress")]
        public LocationContactAndAddress LocationContactAndAddress { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("locationType")]
        public string LocationType { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class LocationContactAndAddress
    {
        [JsonProperty("address")]
        public LastUpdatedDestinationAddress Address { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class EstimatedDeliveryTimeWindow
    {
        [JsonProperty("window")]
        public ReturnDetail Window { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class ReturnDetail
    {
    }

    public partial class LatestStatusDetail
    {
        [JsonProperty("code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("derivedCode")]
        public string DerivedCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("statusByLocale")]
        public string StatusByLocale { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("scanLocation")]
        public LastUpdatedDestinationAddress ScanLocation { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class OriginLocation
    {
        [JsonProperty("locationContactAndAddress")]
        public LocationContactAndAddress LocationContactAndAddress { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("locationId")]
        public string LocationId { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class PackageDetails
    {
        [JsonProperty("packagingDescription")]
        public PackagingDescription PackagingDescription { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sequenceNumber")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long SequenceNumber { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("count")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long Count { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("weightAndDimensions")]
        public WeightAndDimensions WeightAndDimensions { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("packageContent")]
        public object[] PackageContent { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class PackagingDescription
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class WeightAndDimensions
    {
        [JsonProperty("weight")]
        public Weight[] Weight { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("dimensions")]
        public Dimension[] Dimensions { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Dimension
    {
        [JsonProperty("length")]
        public long Length { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("width")]
        public long Width { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("height")]
        public long Height { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("units")]
        public string Units { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Weight
    {
        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("unit")]
        public string Unit { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Information
    {
        [JsonProperty("contact")]
        public ReturnDetail Contact { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("address")]
        public LastUpdatedDestinationAddress Address { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class ScanEvent
    {
        [JsonProperty("date")]
        public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("eventType")]
        public string EventType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("eventDescription")]
        public string EventDescription { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("exceptionCode")]
        public string ExceptionCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("exceptionDescription")]
        public string ExceptionDescription { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("scanLocation")]
        public ScanLocation ScanLocation { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("locationId", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string LocationId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("locationType")]
        public string LocationType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("derivedStatusCode")]
        public string DerivedStatusCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("derivedStatus")]
        public string DerivedStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class ScanLocation
    {
        [JsonProperty("streetLines")]
        public string[] StreetLines { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("city", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("stateOrProvinceCode", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string StateOrProvinceCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("postalCode", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long? PostalCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("countryCode", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("residential")]
        public bool Residential { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("countryName", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class ServiceDetail
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("shortDescription")]
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class ShipmentDetails
    {
        [JsonProperty("possessionStatus")]
        public bool PossessionStatus { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("weight")]
        public Weight[] Weight { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class SpecialHandling
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("paymentType")]
        public string PaymentType { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class StandardTransitTimeWindow
    {
        [JsonProperty("window")]
        public Window Window { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Window
    {
        [JsonProperty("ends")]
        public DateTimeOffset Ends { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class TrackingNumberInfo
    {
        [JsonProperty("trackingNumber")]
        public string TrackingNumber { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("trackingNumberUniqueId")]
        public string TrackingNumberUniqueId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("carrierCode")]
        public string CarrierCode { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class TrackyThing
    {
        public static TrackyThing FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TrackyThing>(json, HackyTracky.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this TrackyThing self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, HackyTracky.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }

    internal class ParseStringConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(long) || t == typeof(long?);

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
            var value = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
            long l;
            if (Int64.TryParse(value, out l))
            {
                return l;
            }
            throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type long");
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (untypedValue == null)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
                return;
            }
            var value = (long)untypedValue;
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ToString());
            return;
        }

        public static readonly ParseStringConverter Singleton = new ParseStringConverter();
    }
}
```

There are other services that do the same thing - json2csharp is popular too

After you've done this, you can just convert your objects like it says in the comment at the top of the classes:

```
var trackyThing = TrackyThing.FromJson(jsonString);
```

And access things via LINQ:

```
var allScanEvents = trackyThing.Output.CompleteTrackResults
  .SelectMany(ctr => ctr.TrackResults)
  .SelectMany(tr => tr.ScanEvents);
```